# add location block by referencing an existing server

Tags: nginx

I'm using [a third-party Heroku buildpack for nginx](https://github.com/agriffis/nginx-buildpack) with .conf:

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        server_name _;
        ...
    }
    include config/nginx-local*.conf
}
```

Clearly it's preferable to do my own configuration in the included file instead of editing this one.

I want to serve static files on `/assets`. Being new to nginx, I naïvely tried:

```
server {
    server_name static;
    location /assets {
        root <disk location>
    }
}
```

But then I [discovered](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) that `server_name` is supposed to be the server location, e.g. `www.example.org`. Since I don't want to use a subdomain, adding a new `server` block seems like a bad fit.

So is there a way to reference the *existing* `server` block, and add a `location` block to it from the top-level `http` context?

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's a long document - are you just referring to my use of `root` inside `location`? I have actually since changed that, but it's tangent to my problem and question here.